How can I throw more accurately?
Between Grenades and Strategems I really need to up my throwing game. Are there any tips for being more accurate with throwing?
I have seen an armour, I am yet to unlock (I am lv17) , which adds 30% to throw distance, but I am not sure what the default throw distance is.
Folks in Quickplay I have played with mentioned it being 50 meters, but I still seem to be short on throws.

The grenade/strategem throwing is a bit difficult to get use to.  Most times I guestimate it, and usually its "good enough".  The only really hard part is throwing grenades into enemy spawn-points, especially the Automation ones.

I found a YouTube short from Gamespot, which has some tips for this.

Use the map marker ping to judge distance which will tell you how far away something is

Q on PC
R1 on PS


The video says a standard throw is 42 meters and enhanced throw is 60 meters
Reddit suggests regular is 44m and boosted is 66m
Reddit suggests you can dive and throw to achieve ~90m

I have confirmed the 90 meter throw myself, it's about the timing and some height helps.
Throwing a stratagem ~90m
Also some physics on throwing from our friends over at the Physics StackExchange who say 45 degrees will get the most distance.
